# Minimax statistical estimation of proximal transform $\mbox{prox}_g(\theta_0)$, from linear model data $y_i := x_i^\top \theta_0 + \epsilon_i$

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, convex-analysis, learning-theory

**tl;dr:** *My question pertains the subject of minimax estimation theory (mathematical statistics), in the context of linear regression.*

---

Given a vector $\theta_0 \in \mathbb R^d$, consider the linear model data
$$
y_i = x_i^\top \theta_0 + \epsilon_i,
$$
where the $x_i$'s are iid from $N(0,I)$, and the $\epsilon_i$'s are iid noise variables from $N(0,\sigma^2)$, independent of the $x_i$'s.

Let $g:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ be a convex function (e.g an $\ell_p$ norm for $p \in [1,2]$), and set
$$
\theta_1 = \theta_1(\theta_0) := \mbox{prox}_g(\theta_0),
$$
where $\mbox{prox}_g:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^d$ is the proximal operator of $g$ defined by
$$
\mbox{prox}_g(\theta_0) = \arg\min_{\theta \in \mathbb R^d}(1/2)\|\theta-\theta_0\|^2 + g(\theta).
$$

Fix $s \in [1,d]$ and $R \ge 0$, and consider the following minimax problem
$$
\inf_{\widehat \theta_1}\sup_{\theta_0} \|\widehat \theta_1-\theta_1(\theta_0)\|^2,
\tag{1}
$$
where the supremum if over all choices of $\theta_0$ such that $\|\theta_0\|_2 \le R$ and $\|\theta_0\|_0 \le s$, and the infimum is over all estimators of $\widehat \theta_1$ of $\theta_1(\theta_0)$, based on the finite dataset $D_n:=\{(x_1,y_1),\ldots,(x_n,y_n)\}$.

> **Question.** How can I go about computing a good lower-bound for the value of (1), as a function of $d$, $n$, $s$, and $R$ ?